# Naming database table fields to designate relationships?

Tags: database, naming-conventions

Lets say I have tables Student and Mentor

Does anyone use naming convention for relationship as below? I think this way is good to see the relationships quickly. Would anyone suggest a better way?

Student

StudentID
StudentName
Student2MentorID

Answer (score 1):

To start from scratch, - you probably know this already - there are several ways to represent your database schema, I mean, by using diagrams, for example [ER-diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Diagramming_conventions) that helps you (and your team) stay up to date with your database's design and thus making it simpler to understand.

Now, personally when it comes to implementation, I do use some kind of naming-convention. For example:

- For large projects, I use double underscores to split between table categories, (ie. `hr__personnel`, `hr__clocks`, `hr__timetable`, `vehicles__cars`, `vehicles__trips`) and so on.
- Now, having a relationship between two tables, I do Include both (or all) of the involved table names. (ie. `hr__personnel_timetable`, `vehicles__cars_trips`, etc)
- Sometimes, (as we all know), we cannot follow strictly a standard, so in those cases I use my own criteria when choosing large relationships' names.
- As a rule, I also name table attributes by a three-letter preffix. For example, in my table `trips`, my fields will be `tri_id`,`tri_distance`, `tri_elapsed`
- Note also, that in the above item, I didn't include a Foreign Key. So here I go then. When it comes to FK's, It's easy for me (and my team) to realize that the field IS a FK. 
  If we follow the previous example, I would like to know who drives in each trip (to make it easier, we assume that only one person drives one trip). So my table now is something like this: `tri_id`, *`per_id`*, `tri_distance`, `tri_elapsed`. Now you can easily realize that per_id is just a foreign field of the table. Just, another hint to help.

Just by following these simple steps, you will save *hours*, and probably some headaches too.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think: you can add prefix (3 letters) to table depending that module represents (scholar,sales,store)

module: scholar ->**sc**
table: **scStudent** ( IdStudent,nameStudent..)

table: **scMentor**(IdMentor,nameMentor...)

relationship

**scMentorStudent** (**IdMentorStudent** pk..)

You can use Microsoft's EF notation :
    http://weblogs.asp.net/jamauss/pages/DatabaseNamingConventions.aspx

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. It is useful.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use underscores... 
I suggest to simply use existing naming convention rules such as this one:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/naming-conventions.php